# Must new tables be created in hook_update_N()?

Tags: database, updating

When you create a new table in `hook_schema()`, should that table be added in a `hook_update_N()` as well? Or is there some trick, or something I missed, to have databae-updates automatically add tables?

The documentation of hook_update_N() does not explain anything about introducing new tables, whereas the [documentation of `hook_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) says:

> The tables declared by this hook will be automatically created **when the module is first enabled**, and removed when the module is uninstalled.

(Highlight is mine)

And if so, how to best avoid duplicating the schema definitions for the new table in both hook_update_N() and hook_schema(). Simply referring to the schema as follows:

```
 function hook_update_N(&$sandbox) {
   $schema = hook_schema();
   $name = "foo";
   $table = $schema["foo"];
   db_create_table($name, $table);
 }
```

Seems to work, but on changing the table again, will fail if a user runs the updates and gets to run two or more hook_update_N()s. After all: the first hook_update_N will then already install the correct database and the second hook_update_M() will try to add/change/alter columns that were already up-to-date.

How do you deal with this?

Comment: Refer to http://drupal.org/node/150215 for documentation. So basically to add a new table after a module is installed is via hook_update_N but you also add the table definition to the hook_schema for new users or fresh installs. So sum it up if you make any table changes to update the current tables via hook_update_N but you also merge the changes in the hook_schema.

Comment: So there is no way to avoid violating DRY, it seems. Pity.

Comment: nothing that I am aware of. But you can write a small function which has the schema definition and call that definition in both the functions.

Comment: @berkes One could define another function that returns the additional schema and refer to it in both the update and install hooks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So just a copy paste from drupal.org. You also need to add the schema definition to hook_schema.

```
/**
 * Create new database table {mytable2}.
 */
function mymodule_update_7101() {
  $schema['mytable2'] = array(
     // table definition array goes here
  );
  db_create_table('mytable2', $schema['mytable2']);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that there is no other way then copying the table-definition from hook_schema() into hook_update_N(). In other words: that there is no way to avoid violating DRY?

Comment: @berkes spot on...there's a very good explanation why that is [here](http://drupal.org/node/150220) in case you haven't already seen it

Comment: @Clive That is an awesome example. Never saw it before.  +1

Comment: @junedkazi There's a link to it on the link you provided in your comment ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's worth to mention that `db_create_table` function is deprecated and has been removed from Drupal 9. Instead you should use:

```
/**
* Create new database table {mytable2}.
*/
function mymodule_update_9000() {
  $schema['mytable2'] = [
     // table definition array goes here
  ];
  \Drupal::database()->schema()->createTable('mytable2', $schema['mytable2']);
}
```